# Why is link styling applying to all elements, even though it should be for just one element

Tags: css, hyperlink

Why is it that the links on [this](http://eighttwentydesign.com/portfolio/mobileapps) page (and all others but best to demo) sharing the link style accross all pages. To demo this click on Portfolio then go back, you will see the link text turns white, even though this should only be for the "message" element (blue with rounder corners) at the bottom of the page?

This is my CSS

```
.message {
background-color:#54a0d9;
border:1px solid #54a0d9;
color:#fff;
}

.message h2 {
font-size:22px;
color:#fff;
}

.message a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
color:#fff; }
```

and HTML is a normal link inside an element (which is not a child of the message element.

Surely that should only apply to the Message elements?

I've done some research on whats causing this but so far nout...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separating selectors by commas means to consider them completely separately. So here:

```
.message a:link, a:visited
```

Means to apply this style to `a:link`s inside of elements with a class of "message", and also to `a:visited`s. Note that the latter *does not have to be inside of an element of class message*. Simply put `.message` in front of each comma-separated term to fix it.

Comment: Why bother with the pseudo-selectors? Seems like .message a should suffice.